# Improper display of parentheses in fraction of fraction

Tags: math-mode, fractions

The following code:

```
$\dfrac{\left( \dfrac{\left( \dfrac{1}{2}\right) }{2}\right) }{2}$
```

gives a nasty output:
[image]

It seems that the `$\left( \right)$` command doesn't do the job.

Any idea how to solve this in general?

Comment: Stacking fractions is never the best thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use the `\raisebox` command to move down the upper part of your fraction

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\dfrac{\left(\raisebox{-1.5ex}{$\displaystyle\dfrac{\left( \dfrac{1}{2}\right) }{2}$}\right) }{2}$

\end{document}
```

for this output:

[image: Output]

**NOTE** `\raisebox{<length>}{<text>}` is expecting some text so you need to enter in math-mode in the raisebox.

Answer (score 8):

Please always post complete documents showing all packages used.

You can re-align the upper fraction using `\vcenter` (but it still doesn't look very nice).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$\dfrac{\left( \vcenter{\hbox{$\dfrac{\left( \dfrac{1}{2}\right) }{2}$}}\right) }{2}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `\scaleleftright{}{}{}` macro of the `scalerel` package doesn't suffer this problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
$\dfrac{\scaleleftright[2ex]{(}{\dfrac{\left( \dfrac{1}{2}\right) }{2}}{)}}{2}$
\end{document}
```

[image]