# Delimiter size in fraction produces unwanted blank space

Tags: amsmath, delimiters

I am using `amsmath` in a two-column `IEEEtran` document class and at a certain point I typed this equation:

```
\begin{equation}
    A = \sum_{j=1}^{J} \frac{\left[ e^{-\left( \frac{x_1^a}{2\sigma^2} \right)^2} - e^{-\left( \frac{x_2^a}{2\sigma^2} \right)^2} \right]^2}{\Phi\left( \frac{x_1^a}{\sigma} \right) - \Phi\left( \frac{x_2^a}{\sigma} \right)}
\end{equation}
```

The issue is that this code produces the following result:
[image]

As you see, as the exponential is centralized in the brackets of the fraction numerator, there is a strange blank space above the fraction bar. Is there a way to vertically move the content inside the brackets, so I can make this blank space disappear?

Considerations: 1- I cannot use `\exp` instead of `e^{}`, as the former makes the equation longer and it does not fit the linewidth. 2- If I use manually sized delimiter `\Big`, etc, I can adjust this space, but the result does not look good either.

Comment: maybe related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131385/improper-display-of-parentheses-in-fraction-of-fraction or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59747/proper-display-of-fractions

Answer (score 2):

You can correct that by lowering that part:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
A = \sum_{j=1}^{J}
  \frac{\left[ \raisebox{-1ex}{$e^{-\left( \frac{x_1^a}{2\sigma^2} \right)^2} -
                                e^{-\left( \frac{x_2^a}{2\sigma^2} \right)^2}$} \right]^2}
  {\Phi\left( \frac{x_1^a}{\sigma} \right) - \Phi\left( \frac{x_2^a}{\sigma} \right)}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
A = \sum_{j=1}^{J} \frac{\begin{bmatrix}
        \mathrm{e}^{-\Bigl(\mfrac{x_1^a}{2\sigma^2}\Bigr)^2} - \mathrm{e}^{-\Bigl(\mfrac{x_2^a}{2\sigma^2}\Bigr)^2}
        \end{bmatrix}^2}
                        {\Phi\Bigl(\mfrac{x_1^a}{\sigma}\Bigr) - \Phi\Bigl(\mfrac{x_2^a}{\sigma}\Bigr)}
    \end{equation}
or better
    \begin{equation}
    A = \sum_{j=1}^{J}
    \frac{\biggl[\exp\Bigl(-\Bigl(\mfrac{x_1^a}{2\sigma^2}\Bigr)^2\Bigr)
                            - \exp\Bigl(-\Bigl(\mfrac{x_2^a}{2\sigma^2} \Bigr)^2\Bigr)\biggr]^2}
         {\Phi\Bigl(\mfrac{x_1^a}{\sigma}\Bigr) - \Phi\Bigl(\mfrac{x_2^a}{\sigma}\Bigr)}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) The first is exactly what I was working on, but you were faster :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about using (a) inline-fraction notation instead of `\frac{..}` for the "inner" fraction expression and (b) `\exp` notation instead of `e^{...}` notation? Observe that, contrary to the concern you expressed in the posting, the `\exp` notation does **not** make the math expression exceed the available width.

[image]

A side benefit of these notational choices is that the summation symbol to the left of the single remaining `\frac{}{}` term doesn't look all puny and forlorn.

By the way, the summation expression looks odd: the summation is supposed to run over items indexed by the letter `j`, yet there seem to be no terms in the equation that are indexed by `j`.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
A = \sum_{j=1}^{J} 
    \frac{\bigl\{ \exp[-( x_1^a/(2\sigma^2))^2] 
           -\exp[-(x_2^a/(2\sigma^2))^2] \bigr\}^2}{%
          \Phi(x_1^a/\sigma) - \Phi( x_2^a/\sigma)}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: My apologies, sir, you are so right! It just fits nicely with `10pt`.