# Trouble with complex fractions and parentheses

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, fractions

I'm having trouble finding a way to express this fraction with the amsmath package.

[image]

The result I'm getting isn't quite nice. Are there alternative ways to write this fraction?

[image]

```
 \documentclass[10pt,norsk, fleqn]{extarticle}
 \usepackage[a4paper, margin=1.2cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
 \usepackage{amsmath}

 \begin{document}

 $\displaystyle\frac{a}{\displaystyle\frac{b}{\displaystyle\frac{c}{\displaystyle\frac{d}{e}}}}\to\left(\displaystyle\frac{\left(\displaystyle\frac{\left(\displaystyle\frac{\left(\displaystyle\frac{a}{b}\right)}{c}\right)}{d}\right)}{e}\right)$

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Why not inline: `(((a/b)/c)/d)/e`?

Comment: @Sigur I usually do this. But I would like the expanded "big" version at the beginning of the paragraph.

Comment: Possible dublicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131385/improper-display-of-parentheses-in-fraction-of-fraction

Answer (score 5):

Both solutions are horrible, but I don't think you can get any better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array,delarray}

\newcommand{\pfrac}[2]{\begin{array}({@{}>{\displaystyle}c@{}})\frac{#1}{#2}\end{array}}

\newcommand{\leftparen}[1]{%
  \raisebox{-\height}{$\left(\vcenter{\hbox{\vphantom{$#1$}}}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace$}%
}
\newcommand{\rightparen}[1]{%
  \raisebox{-\height}{$\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\vcenter{\hbox{\vphantom{$#1$}}}\right)$}%
}
\newcommand{\bigfrac}[1]{\raisebox{-\height}{$#1$}}

\begin{document}

\[
\pfrac{\pfrac{\pfrac{\pfrac{a}{b}}{c}}{d}}{e}
\]

\[
\leftparen{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{c}}{d}}{e}}
\leftparen{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{c}}{d}}
\leftparen{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{c}}
\leftparen{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\bigfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{c}}{d}}{e}}
\rightparen{\dfrac{a}{b}}
\rightparen{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{c}}
\rightparen{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{c}}{d}}
\rightparen{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{c}}{d}}{e}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The second one looks like a wireless sign emanating from the tower... :)

Comment: @Sigur Your comment is beautiful. I am not a person who often makes many compliments but the answers of egreg are wonderful.

Comment: @Sebastiano, I agree. So wonderful that leads me to see beyond the math... lol